# how to translate curl command in powershell

Tags: powershell, curl

I've this command:

```
curl -s -L --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:XXXX" https://myuri/"
```

And I need to convert to PowerShell

I've tried this, but doesn't works:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{"AUTHORIZATION"="XXXXXX"} -Uri https://myUri
```

I've also tried this:

```
PS > $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
PS > $headers.Add("Authorization","XXXXXX")
PS > $headers.Add("Accept","application/json")
PS > $headers.Add("Content-Type","application/json")
PS> $uri = "https://myUri"
PS> $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Get -ContentType "application/json"
PS> $response
PS>
```

but the `$response` is empty.

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one that I used to authenticate to Teamcity

```
    function Connect-to-Teamcity ($userName, $password, $tcServer, $uri)
    {
        $auth = $username + ':' + $password

        $Encoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($auth)
        $EncodedPassword = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Encoded)


        $headers = @{"Authorization"="Basic $($EncodedPassword)"}

        $url = "http://$tcServer/httpAuth/app/rest"

        $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$url/$uri" -Header $headers -Method Get

        return $result
    }
```

Here is another example if you have more than one header Item:

```
    $resourceAppIdURI = "https://graph.windows.net"
    # Login to Azure and get a token valid for accessing the graph API
    $authority = "https://login.windows.net/$adTenant"
    $authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority
    $authResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($resourceAppIdURI, $clientId, $redirectUri, "Auto")
    # Add the token to the header of all future calls to the graph API
    $headers = @{"Authorization"=$authResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader();"Content-Type"="application/json"}
$uri = [string]::Format("https://graph.windows.net/{0}/groups/{1}/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.5", $adTenant, $groupId)
$body = @"
    {
        "id": $appRoleId,
        "principalId": $groupId,
        "principalType": "Group",
        "resourceId": $appObjectId
    }
"@
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method "POST" -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $Body
```

Comment: Hi Thom, thanks for your answer, but I need to use the PRIVATE-TOKEN. Could you help me on this?

Comment: IF that is a header item then                                $headers = @{"PRIVATE-TOKEN"='private token value'

Comment: In bash command curl I've used the -head parameter to get value of X-Total-Page from gitlab. How can I get the same results ?